# How To Add RecyclerView Slide In Animation for New Item

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView and add items to `mCommentArrayList` at index 0. I am trying to create a slide-in animation at the top of the view as new items (CardViews) are added to the RecyclerView.

I know there are libraries that can be used, and I have even explored https://github.com/wasabeef/recyclerview-animators. However, the documentation is limited and I am unsure what approach to take.

Note that I add all new items to my `mCommentArrayList` at `index 0` so that they appear at the top of the view. I know there is some work to be done in the adapter, specifically `onBindViewHolder()`, but I don't know exactly what to put in order to activate the animations.

Where I first call to Firebase to find data to populate the RecyclerView:

```
    mUpdateRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            setImage(dataSnapshot);
            setQuestion(dataSnapshot);
            createInitialCommentIDArray(dataSnapshot);
            mNumberOfCommentsAtPoll = (int) dataSnapshot.child(COMMENTS_LABEL).getChildrenCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < mNumberOfCommentsAtPoll; i++) {
                String commentID = (String) dataSnapshot.child(COMMENTS_LABEL).child(mCommentIDArrayList.get(i)).child("COMMENT").getValue();
                Log.v("COMMENT_ID", "The comment ID is " + commentID);
                String userID = (String) dataSnapshot.child(COMMENTS_LABEL).child(mCommentIDArrayList.get(i)).child("USER_ID").getValue();
                Log.v("USER_ID", "The user ID is " + userID);
                mCommentArrayList.add(0, new Comments(mUserAvatar, userID, commentID));
                mCommentAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Subsequent Calls to Firebase on Data Change:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mUpdateComments = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            mNumberOfCommentsAtPoll = (int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
            for (DataSnapshot x : dataSnapshot.child(COMMENTS_LABEL).getChildren()) {
                Log.v("DATA_SNAPSHOT", x.toString());
                if (mCommentIDArrayList.contains(x.getKey())) {
                    Log.v("Comment_Already_Added", x.getKey());
                } else {
                    Log.v("Child_Added_Called", "Child Added Called");
                    mCommentIDArrayList.add(x.getKey());
                    String commentID = (String) dataSnapshot.child(COMMENTS_LABEL).child(x.getKey()).child("COMMENT").getValue();
                    Log.v("New_Comment", "The new comment is " + commentID);
                    String userID = (String) dataSnapshot.child(COMMENTS_LABEL).child(x.getKey()).child("USER_ID").getValue();
                    Log.v("New_User_ID", "The new userID is " + userID);
                    mCommentArrayList.add(0, new Comments(mUserAvatar, userID, commentID));
                    mPollCommentsList.getAdapter().notifyItemInserted(0);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using the library you were talking about (https://github.com/wasabeef/recyclerview-animators) it's very easy to add a `SlideInAnimator` to your `RecyclerView`. Just use the following code to set an `Animator` to your `RecyclerView` (pick one):

```
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new SlideInDownAnimator());
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new SlideInRightAnimator());
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new SlideInLeftAnimator());
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new SlideInUpAnimator());
```

Once you have done this the you can simply trigger the animation by calling `notifyItemInserted(position)` or `notifyItemRangeInserted(positionStart, itemCount)`. These calls will trigger the `Animator`, calling `notifyDatasetChanged()` **won't**.

Triggering the insertion animation:

```
    recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyItemInserted(position);
    recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyItemRangeInserted(positionStart, itemCount);
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a shot, so I completely eliminate use of notifyDataSetChanged() when calling an animation?

Comment: Yes. If you want your animations to work, do not rely on calling notifyDataSetChanged(); as it is the RecyclerView's default behavior, animations are not triggered to start inside this method.

Comment: It actually did not work. Nothing at all is appearing in the view. I removed notifyDataSetChanged() and added the notifyItemInserted() method. I can create a new SO post and show the code?

Answer (score 6):

**Hope this code help's you !**

create one animation file animation_from_right.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:duration="700"
android:fillAfter="false"
>

<translate
android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
android:fromXDelta="100%p"
android:toXDelta="0"
/>

<alpha
android:fromAlpha="0.5"
android:toAlpha="1"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
/>

</set>
```

in Activity

```
Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mActivity, R.anim.animation_from_right);
        holder.itemView.startAnimation(animation);
```

use above code in your Adapter on onBindViewHolder

Comment: Saurabh this is the easy and perfect solution. +1

Answer (score 0):

The best way animate the recyclerview will be to do it in the `onbindviewholder method`.

Here is how to do it-

create a field variable lastAnimatedPosition in the adapter class.

```
private int lastAnimatedPosition = -1;
```

Then in the onbindviewholder-

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Comments comment = mDataSet.get(position);
        holder.userComment.setText(comment.getUserComment());
        holder.userID.setText("User " + position);
if (position > lastAnimatedPosition) {
      lastAnimatedPosition = position;
      Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.my_anim_set);
      animation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
      ((ViewHolder) holder).container.setAnimation(animation);
      animation.start();
    }
    }
```

Next a few tweaks in your viewholder class-

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // each data item is just a string in this case
        protected ImageView userAvatar;
        protected TextView userID;
        protected TextView userComment;
        **protected View container;**


        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            **container = v;**
            userAvatar = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
            userID = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.user_ID);
            userComment = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.user_comment_textview);
        }

        **public void clearAnimation() {
          container.clearAnimation();
        }**
    }
```

And lastly simply override `onViewDetachedFromWindow`-

```
@Override
  public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(final ViewHolder holder) {
    holder.clearAnimation();
  }
```

**UPDATE**

Since the element to be animated is in the 0th index replace the `if (position > lastAnimatedPosition)` snippet with -

```
if (position == 0) {
      lastAnimatedPosition = position;
      Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.my_anim_set);
      animation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
      ((ViewHolder) holder).container.setAnimation(animation);
      animation.start();
    }
```

Comment: Much appreciated, I am going to give it a shot. Keep in mind that each new item is added at the "0" index. Not sure how that would work with the onBindViewHolder method, as I am noticing all views sliding in and not just the newest....

Comment: You are right.... This will make all elements sliding in. For the "0"  index problem I have updated my answer.

Comment: Much appreciated, I will let you know. What does the override to onViewDetachedFromWindow() actually do? I am a bit confused on its purpose/function.

Comment: This tells the view is no longer attached to the window. I have used this to tell the code that the view is no longer attached and hence it should stop animations. If we don't clear the animations here, we will get a lot of UI glitches when we are scrolling fast.

Comment: Got it, much appreciated.