# Repopulate recycleview data on left-right swipe gesture

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager

I am designing a layout in which I have 3 `RecycleView`s which is depicted in the picture, the leftmost 'purple' `RecycleView` is fixed. The next two `RecycleView`s data is changed on swipe. Kind of like a table, I simply repopulate these `RecycleViews` with new `List` data. Now normally swipe is used in `RecycleView` for one item, here I want to add swipe gesture for whole list.

[image]

This is what I have done, but the swipe is only for one element and for some reasons it doesn't populate `RecycleView`. however the same method is working for click next button. I know this could be done using `ViewPager` but I am still looking if there is some swipe method for `RecycleView` which lets me repopulate whole `RecycleView` instead of swipe on one single item data.

```
 ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback simpleItemTouchCallback = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT | ItemTouchHelper.DOWN | ItemTouchHelper.UP) {

        @Override
        public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "on Move", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int swipeDir) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "on Swiped ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //Remove swiped item from list and notify the RecyclerView
            adapterOdds1.updateListOdds(allBestSiteGamesList.get(oddsListDipslay), oddsListDipslay);
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ItemTouchHelper` will not help in this case, since i want to use swipe for whole list, so i found the following solution helpful to implement the desired feature that i wanted without need to use `viewpager`.

His solution helped solve my problem. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50969707/3952885